# How to make streaming MP4 from reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I try to make little youtube. I have two servers.

1. Backend server Ubuntu16. Server has application + mp4 files.

Django + uWSGI +

NGINX

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid    /etc/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
       }

http {
  upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000; 
                  }
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name XXX.XXX.XXX.191;
    charset     utf-8;
    gzip            on;
    gzip_static     on;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_min_length 1024;    
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
    if_modified_since off;   
    add_header Accept-Ranges bytes;
     location /static/ {
         root  /home/tube;
                       }
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     uwsgi_params;
               }
}
}
```

When I load page with video from browser using http://www.backend/, I see: 
1.mp4 - answer 206 - chunk 2mb. After I click to play, the video starts to play chunk by chunk with answer 206. Seems to be correct. This is backend server (it has public access )

2. Frontend server Ubuntu16. NGINX as reverse proxy.

> ```
> user  www-data;
> worker_processes  auto;
> pid    /etc/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;
> events {worker_connections  1024;}
> http {
>     include       mime.types;
>     default_type  application/octet-stream;
>     server {
>          listen       80;
>          server_name  XXX.XXX.XXX.92;
>          proxy_http_version 1.1;
>          proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
>          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
>          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
>          proxy_set_header Range $http_range;
>          proxy_set_header If-Range $http_if_range;
>          proxy_no_cache $http_range $http_if_range;
>          location / {
>                 proxy_pass  http://XXX.XXX.XXX.191/;
>                     }
>         }
>     }
> ```

When I load the same page with video from browser using http://www.frontend/
I see:
1.mp4 - answer 200 - preload starts until full lenght of video (~150mb), instead 2mb chunk. After preload finished, I can click play and video starts streaming, loading mp4 again (answer 200)

I want that frontend server streaming videos correctly. First chunk 2-4mb after I load html, the rest chunks after i click play.